# Blender 2.8 manipulators

Tags: 3d-manipulator

[image]

Is there any way to set these manipulators on the keyboard ? How can i set Move, Rotate and scale to W E R keys ?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to switch your active tool so that you get the widget, or are you asking how to set your short cut keys to the operator? I have found that if my shortcut is G to translate that I can press the shortcut and move my selection even when my active tool is something else.

Comment: Should be like this [link](https://uploadir.com/u/fa5u1li3)

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the icon, then choose assign shorcut. Then you have to save the user preferences (Edit>>Preferences). In this menu you will find the keymap too.

Comment: Should be like this [link](https://uploadir.com/u/fa5u1li3) if possible

Comment: Oh wait, actually, your option helped, thank you!